# No SQL database or Graph database for data intensive application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, neo4j, graph-databases, database

I am building an rails application which will have huge amount of user and their activities and tasks and dynamic attributes. Currently I am using `postgresql` but I know it is not a good choice this kind of application.

I am a confused between `Graph databases` and 'Nosql databases` which one to choose.

Comment: This question, in its current context is too subjective to offer any real factual answers. Too little is known about your scenario to give something meaningful back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A graph database *is* a NoSQL database, as is a document database, column-store database, and a key/value database. Regarding which one to choose: Unfortunately that cannot be answered so simply, as a lot will depend on your specific application.

But... why choose *one*? Each type of NoSQL data store has its specific advantages. You can build a system based on multiple data stores, each one used to its specific advantage(s). This concept is known as *polyglot persistence*.

The Microsoft Patterns & Practices team published [guidance](http://dataguidance.codeplex.com/) around this very topic, and I'd suggest reading through it. You can also check out the book [NoSQL Distilled](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321826620) which also goes into this topic and the specifics of each data store classification.

If you want to see an example of an app built on several data stores, check out [Cloud Ninja Polyglot Persistence](http://cn2p.codeplex.com). Members of my team (including myself) got together and built this as a learning/training exercise.